# What is a shop called that sells music CDs?

Tags: meaning, professions

What is a shop called that sells music CDs (American English)? Such shops also offer some classic or traditional music on other forms of media — vinyl or cassettes. However they do not sell music instruments or offers music classes (see photo).

[image: Man browsing CDs in specialist shop]

Comment: Do they still exist? Where I live in Italy, a smallish city, these have become obsolete. Nowadays, the only places where you can buy CDs are in supermarkets. Everyone, or nearly,  downloads their music.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - yes, there still are record stores in Italy as well as in other countries.

Comment: @Josh I said in the smallish Italian city where I live, my question was rhetorical. In London they're closing down fast, only the largest department stores are still open.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - record shops are surviving offering CDs which are difficult to find online and vinyls that are back into fashion. People still love human contact  shopping :)

Comment: [*Phonograph cylinders*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonograph_cylinder) might be found in an antique shop if you are lucky

Comment: In the US they're mostly still called "record stores".  But they're mostly gone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: My experience in the last couple of years is the opposite of what you suggest: a good number of record stores are suriving across Europe (I can vouch for at least Stockholm, York, and Ljubljana within the last few months), but as small specialist shops catering to enthusiasts — it’s the medium-to-large places that have closed, since the public in general have moved on to downloads.

Comment: @PLL in every corner in London there used to be a record shop, then tape cassettes came along, and youngsters began taping music off the radio. Record shops didn't suffer because the quality of the audio tapes were always crap compared to the original disc. The slump came with CDs and computers, suddenly we could burn our favourite music and make decent copies. Then broadband became accessible to nearly everyone, and downloading music became super easy. Consequently, I've stopped buying new CDs as they are overpriced in Italy. The Italian record industry is in crisis.

Comment: I believe they are called **_obsolete**: No longer in use._

Comment: Almost no shop sells *just* CDs anymore, but if they sell CDs, DVDs and games, they're sometimes called 'media stores'.

Comment: Wow, Daddy, that’s like a stand up Amazon with instant delivery?!

Comment: [`Wrecka stow`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yEbZKdhV-g), depending on your dialect. ([*Under The Cherry Moon*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092133/))

Comment: BTW its strange that people seem to think "record" means "vinyl disk".  ("Hah hah, they still call CD shops record shops!")  When the vinyl disks came out, did people laugh "hah hah, they still call them "recordings" instead of "vinyl disks"" ... ?

Comment: .. I mean, forget the app store etc .. what you download on BitTorrent are .. "recordings".  What else would you call them???

Comment: I think a critical point for the OP here is that ***it would be utterly commonplace to, indeed, call this a 'music shop'***.  The OP seems to think  that since a shop which sells guitars, violins might (also, sometimes) be called a "music shop" (as well as a number of other names), then you wouldn't call a record shop a music shop.  Indeed, OP, it is utterly commonplace to call a record shop a music shop. Indeed, the few large music superstores remaining would very likely call themselves "music superstores" rather than "record superstores" (or, media superstores, or whatever).

Comment: This comes up a lot on this site - non-native speakers find it surprising! about ambiguity in English.   Indeed, English is utterly, pervasively, overwhelmingly ambiguous, as a commonplace matter.  Indeed there are any number of examples of "kinds of shops" (say, "food shop") which are completely ambiguous in English, without context.

Comment: @FighterJet In third world countries you still find plenty of these, they usually sell DVDs too though.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The somewhat outdated title is ***Record Store*** or ***Record Shop***.

Comment: "Daddy, what's a shop?"

Comment: The overwhelming point in this QA, user186499, is that **it is totally, completely irrelevant to naming** if technology changes the underlying "thing", this has always been the case.  If you're not a native English speaker this is totally the norm in English. Your question is just like asking: **"Wow "films" are not made of film any more! What are they called now?!"**

Comment: @Fattie Is that necessarily true?  I still use the term "books on tape" but I feel like it dates me a bit.

Comment: note that it could "sound old fashioned" but then - very many terms sound old fashioned.  still they are often (a) perfectly widely understood and (b) there's no replacement

Comment: @Casey This is similar to how the "Save" icon in computer software is usually represented as a 3.5" floppy disk despite these being obsolete for years and unrecognisable to younger people. The meaning persists even though the archetype it is based on is redundant.

Comment: @Casey I still buy books on tape, produced by the company called books on tape, their product is called, you guessed it "books on tape". I do all my buying from Audible.

Comment: @Fattie *motion pictures*, *movies*… I never “film” anything on my DSLR; I *record* it.

Comment: @Casey: no, it's not *necessarily* true. Sometimes a change of technology does result in a name change, there's no ironclad rule of English to prevent that ever happening. However, it's unremarkable when no change happens.

Comment: Given that what they sell is media which records a performance, and has always been whether the media supporting the record was wax, shellac, vinyl, polycarbonate, or silicon, there is nothing outdated in this name. Just that 'buying a record' meant 'buying a record on vinyl' for some years rather than other media doesn't mean that the shop is a vinyl shop.

Comment: @JDługosz They're referred to as "films" in the UK and Ireland.  (Or "movies", sure; "motion picture" seems to be studio-speak that isn't used by actual human beings.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby or 'flicks' but they don't flicker much now-a-days either.

Comment: @Nathan Sure.  But I feel like "audiobooks" is displacing the older term.

Comment: When I want to ask the time without using my voice, I tap my wrist. The other person is never wearing a wristwatch, and they know to pull their phone out of their pocket and tell me the time

Comment: @DrEval - "Daddy, what's a record?"

Comment: @Fattie also, it has been over 20 years since I have literally "dialed" a phone number. Everyone still uses the verb "to dial" rather than substituting "to pushbutton", "to enter", "to key", or "to type" a phone number.

Comment: hi @JDługosz, the fact that one or two folks (such as yourself) don't use the word "film" is an interesting curiosity.  visit any film set to see extensive use of the word "film".  certainly language changes and in 400 years the word "film" and the word "car" may not be used.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: Soon: "Daddy, what's a Daddy?"

Comment: @Fattie I suppose the Film Industry is keeping it alive as a term of art.  Much to the dismay of the people in the [film industry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_film#Processes).

Comment: @chiliNUT that failed for me recently.  I wanted to remind my mother-in-law (who doesn’t speak English) to mind the time, as she was cooking something and had forgotten something boiling before.  She thought I was asking where I left my watch.

Answer (score 44):

***[Record store](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/record-store)***, also Record shop:

> - an outlet that sells recorded music

(Collins Dictionary)

As shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=record%20shop%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crecord%20shop%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecord%20shop%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecord%20shop%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) "record shop" is the more common definition in BrE while (see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=record%20store%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crecord%20store%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecord%20store%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crecord%20store%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)) "record store" is more common in AmE.

***[Spillers Records](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spillers_Records)*** in Cardiff, Wales, founded in 1894 by Henry Spiller, is reputed to be the oldest record shop in the world. It originally specialised in the sale of phonographs, cylinders and shellac discs. (The world's oldest record shop: [on the vinyl frontier since 1894](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2012/mar/25/spillers-cardiff-worlds-oldest-record-store)).

(Wikipedia)(The Guardian)

[America's oldest](http://www.vinylives.com/history.html) record store, ***George's Song Shop***:

> - First opened in 1932, George's currently enjoys the distinction of being the oldest existing record store in America.
> - [George’s Song Shop](http://www.georgessongshop.com/) was know as Bernie George’s Song Shop from 1932-1941. The sign outside read Bernie George’s Song Shop until 1961.

(www.vinylives.com)

Comment: I don't know whether I agree with this. If someone said "record store" to me I would infer they meant a place which primarily sells vinyl.

Comment: @Michael - well, that may be a question of personal age, younger people would more likely think about CDs.

Comment: CD sales are plummeting. They're irrelevant to young people now.

Comment: One thing that I've always thought was interesting was that it's "album" that has endured as a term for the item itself through format changes, even though its literal meaning stopped applying once LPs were introduced.

Comment: @Michael - I didn't say young  people, but younger people, those who grew up buying  CDs rather than vinyls.

Comment: Until I can purchase all the music I want as FLAC files, I'll keep buying CDs.

Comment: @Michael perhaps ironically, Vinyl sales have been making a huge comeback. [Sales have reached a 25 year high](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2017/jan/03/record-sales-vinyl-hits-25-year-high-and-outstrips-streaming)

Answer (score 6):

Back when such things mattered, growing up in the US we called them "music stores".

Comment: I grew up in the US too, but for me a "music store" did and does means a shop where you buy musical instruments and accessories.   A physical location is old-fashioned, but still important for many customers who wish to  play a number of instruments before choosing one.

Comment: To me, in the US, "music store" is ambiguous, but is most likely to refer to a shop that deals in musical instruments and their accessories.

Comment: @HotLicks Though it is ambiguous, record stores are in fact also called music stores. This is correct. Many record stores or chains have the word "music" in their name, even, rather than "record".  Also, there are stores that sell both: in one stop, you can get a few records and a guitar. :)

Comment: I'm old, so ymmv, but to me a "music store" sells sheet music.  It is also used to refer to stores that sell instruments as well (and which may also sell CDs, etc.)  If what you want is primarily recorded music (be it on CD, tape, vinyl, 8-track, etc.), you want a "record store."

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Where I grew up I don't think there were any stores that specialized in sheet music. It was usually just a section of a store that sold records (we called them "record stores") or instruments (we called them "music stores").

Comment: Yeah, there were likely many variations, depending on the size of the town, the area of the country, and the local culture.  It's pretty much "matter of opinion" stuff.

Comment: Here in San Francisco, we had Byron Hoyt, the big one (huge) plus smaller ones like Sunset Music -- but I think all the dedicated (printed) music stores are gone now.  8^(

Comment: Yeah, now that you mention it, I can see how "music store" could be ambiguous.  Locally, there's still a "Rasputin Music" which sells CDs, but no instruments or sheet music.

Comment: In British English, I would also expect the main business of a "music shop" to be selling musical instruments and sheet music. A seller of recorded music would be a "record shop" but there's no contradiction in "Rasputin Music" being a record shop (cc @JS.).

Answer (score 6):

If  it     sells only recorded  music, Americans  usually  call  it a   record  store,  no  matter  the   media.   This  is   analogous   to    considering   the  store  to  be  part  of  a  database  of   music, one  recording being  a record regardless  of  the physical    media.  Each piece of music, whether  collected into an album or  individually  would 
 be a file.

I believe  anyone  who grew  up    with  iTunes  would 
 agree since that's  the model   Apple used   when designing iTunes.   The  Youtube   generation might see  it different,  but 
 still in terms of data storage.   If  the  store's inventory 
 includes audio books,  paperbacks  and  hardbacks  in  addition to  recorded music, it is called a bookstore.  Barnes&Noble is an  example of    a  bookstore  that  sells  music.

Comment: Some sort of citation would be good, but this is a great answer. Welcome to the stack.

Comment: I remember when the school library was renamed to the media center.  I don’t think it caught on.

Comment: Can't help laughing at this answer thinking the "iTunes generation" and the "Youtube generation" aren't the same thing!

Comment: @AndyT: well, "generations" of technology and "generations" of humans aren't the same thing, causing some confusion. Used to be a generation of humans was 20-30 years. I think for these purposes "the previous generation" means something like "someone who left high school around the time you started it" ;-) The significant difference is that original iTunes users had a music collection whereas YouTube users basically don't (at least, not on YouTube -- they may *also* use iTunes or Spotify or own a CD player or whatever).

Comment: "If the store's inventory includes audio books, paperbacks and hardbacks in addition to recorded music, it is called a bookstore." Not necessarily. You give Barnes&Noble as example of a bookstore that sells music, but there's no reason you can't also have a record store that sells books. It depends on what their primary line of business is.

Answer (score 0):

These days, most places that sell CD's we call a "Thrift store".  We might also say "garage sale", or "flea market", or "street hustler".

Comment: Hard to say if that answer is incorrect, since the question did not imply secondhand or new sale :)